# unexplained null values in cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I am executing the following code...

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder querything = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String sqlTables = "ZSITESUSES";
    String [] sqlSelect = { "ZUSE_ID"};
    querything.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor cursor = querything.query(db, sqlSelect, "ZSITE_ID=1014", null,null, null, null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

on a database as shown in a database browser below (the db viewer has a glitch where it doesn't show underscores properly - please ignore):

[image: database table as viewed in SQLite Database Browser]

The output is:

```
 >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41e679b0
 0 {
    ZUSE_ID=null
 }
 1 {
    ZUSE_ID=null
 }
 2 {
    ZUSE_ID=null
 }
 <<<<<
```

I'm very inexperienced with databses. The fact that there are three components to the cursor looks correct, but the "ZUSE_ID=null" looks wrong to me. And if I execute cursor.getString(0) the answer is null which is definitely wrong.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** On njzk2's suggestion I changed to using

String [] sqlSelect = { "ZSITE_ID","ZUSE_ID","ZUSE_PERCENT","ZSITEUSE_ID" };

and then the corresponding output was:

```
 >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41ba4570
 0 {
    ZSITE_ID=1014
    ZUSE_ID=null
    ZUSE_PERCENT=10
    ZSITEUSE_ID=null
 }
 1 {
    ZSITE_ID=1014
    ZUSE_ID=null
    ZUSE_PERCENT=30
    ZSITEUSE_ID=null
 }
 2 {
    ZSITE_ID=1014
    ZUSE_ID=null
    ZUSE_PERCENT=70
    ZSITEUSE_ID=null
 }
 <<<<<
```

**EDIT:** This was all so strange that I decided to uninstall and reinstall my app - and lo and behold - everything started working perfectly... arrrggghh!

Comment: what does the dumpcursor method look like?

Comment: AFAIK, its part of the OS... I don't know how to access that.

Comment: what is the `querything` object, how are you specifying what table to query?

Comment: try to select all column to see the rest of the table

Comment: Are you sure the db you're using on the device/emulator is the same database that you're browsing there?

Comment: @njzk2: See edit to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to uninstall and reinstall my app - and lo and behold - everything started working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `dumpCursor()` cannot necessarily print non-string column values. [Internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) it just attempts to [get the column value](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow%28android.database.Cursor%2Cjava.io.PrintStream%29) using [`Cursor.getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) which can return null for non-string column types:

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

Solution: Do not use `dumpCursor()` but implement your own logging as necessary.